# Delete record from php mysql in hierarchical manner

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchical-data

I want to delete record from mysql in hierarchical manner.
i have my database like this

```
id pid
1 0
2 1
3 2
```

i want to delete all above record. please reply with proper function in php mysql.

```
function content_deleted($content_id=0, $parent_id=0)
    {
        if($parent_id==0)
        {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT content_id FROM tbl_content WHERE content_id = $content_id");
        }
        else
        {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT content_id FROM tbl_content WHERE content_parent_id = $content_id");  
        }

        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
            foreach($query->result() as $res)
            {
                $id = $res->content_id;
                if($parent_id==0)
                {
                    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM tbl_content WHERE content_id = $id"); 
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM tbl_content WHERE content_parent_id = $id");
                    $this->content_deleted($content_id, $id);   
                }
            }   
        }
    }
```

this is my function im stucked here it onnly delete one record

Comment: What do you mean by "hierarchical manner"?

Comment: hierarchical manner means n level

Comment: I think he wants to truncate, so that when he deletes all the rows he starts at ID 1.

Comment: You can use foreign keys and ON DELETE CASCADE. In this way, deleting the root element of the tree will delete the entire tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relational databases do not lend themselves easily to tree structures. If you only have `id` and `parent_id` fields, you'll have to do a lot of looping and recursion to work with trees. That's why [Nested Sets or MPTT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPTT) were invented. You should move to that model for your trees and this question will solve itself.

Comment: i have other fields also. id and pid just to give idea of what i want. thanks for this tutorial.

Comment: Well yes, I mean "only `id` and `parent_id` *to handle your tree logic*". By introducing addition `lft` and `rght` fields for MPTT logic you'll make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from your_table order by id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

To turncate a table with php:

```
$SQL = "TRUNCATE TABLE `table_name`";
mysql_query($SQL);
```

this will reset all auto increments. and delete all records in the table.